# Python: string formatting and calling functions

Tags: python, string-formatting

So I'm running in to the string formatting error when trying to pass the arguments num1 and num2 to the function gcd.  I'm not sure how to fix this.  Please bear with me since I'm new to Python programming.  Thanks!

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
from collections import defaultdict

lines = sys.stdin.read()
lineArray = lines.split()
listLength = len(lineArray)

def gcd(a, b):
    c = 0
    if a > b:
        r = a%b
        if r == 0:
            return b
        else:
            return gcd(b, r)
    if a < b:
        c = b
        b = a
        a = c
        return gcd(a, b) 

for x in range(0, listLength):
        num1 = lineArray[x]
        num2 = lineArray[x+1]
        print num1, 'and', num2
        print gcd(num1, num2)

    print 'end'
```

Comment: Please make sure the indentation that you see in your published post is the same as the indentation in your script, and if you are getting an exception, post the full stack trace (all the stuff your interpreter spits out when the error occurs).

Comment: currently gcd(a,b) doesn't have any lines in the function because the indentation of c=0 and if a>b: is wrong

Comment: your problem is indentation. However, even properly indented, the recursive function (calling the same function within that function) never ends. So fixing this indentation, your new question would be why the execution of this function never ends

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty simple. `lineArray` is not a list containing integers, but strings. 
So when you do this:

```
r = a%b
```

It tries to format the string `a`, instead of calculating `a%b`.
To solve this, convert `a` and `b` to integers:

```
def gcd(a, b):
    a,b = int(a),int(b)
    c = 0
    if a > b:
        r = a%b
        if r == 0:
            return b
        else:
            return gcd(b, r)
    if a < b:
        c = b
        b = a
        a = c
        return gcd(a, b)
```

Also, in your `gcd` function, the recursion never ends. Hint: You'll have to check if b is 0.
Hope this helps!